# Collision detection in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get the ball bounce of the bat in my mini tennis game. I'm not sure what methods to implement. Currently the ball bounces and both bats move the aim of the game is for a player to get the ball past the oppositions. Is there any special methods?

Answer (score 2):

For implementing the game boundary's simply create a method that checks collisions(say your boundarys are 150 by 150) so

```
 if(x < 0 | x > 150 | y < 0 | y > 150) { // if ball is within boundary's
       xa = xa * -1; //switch direction of ball(bounce)
       ya = ya * -1;

       score += 1;
 }
```

So when the ball hits the boundary the score goes up one and the ball bounces the ball back, but you can also reset the ball with another method.

Btw you can print text on the screen with

```
  g2d.drawString("Score: " + score, 150, 150); // prints score on screen
```

*EDIT* this kind of explains collisions for a basic pong game, it might help a little in your case.

Heres the full code http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/172211-programing-an-applet-game-of-pong/

```
public void checkCollision(){  

    //remember, our ball is 10*10 and the x and y positions are the  

    //top-left corners of the ball. If the top left corner y position  
    //is 0 or 290, we reverse the y- direction that the ball was  

    //travelling in by multiplying ball.dy by -1  

    if(ball.getY() == 0 || ball.getY() == 290){  

        ball.dy = (ball.dy * -1);  

    }  



    //if the ball is at the right-hand edge of the human paddle's  

    //domain and the boolean method hitPaddle() is true, then we  

    //reverse the dx position of ball by multiplying ball.dx by -1  

    if((ball.getX() == 40) && hitPaddle()){  

        ball.dx = (ball.dx * -1);  

    }  



    //we already know that the computer paddle can't miss, so if  

    //the ball reaches the left-hand edge of the paddle, we can make the  

    //dx switch directions without any additional checks  
    if(ball.getX() == 460){  

        ball.dx = (ball.dx * -1);  

    }  



    //if the ball is missed by the human paddle and reaches the   

    //left-hand edge of the applet window, then reset the ball  

    //and increment the score  
    if(ball.getX() == 0){  

        pRight.setScore(pRight.getScore() + 1);  

        ball.reset();  

    }  

 }  


 public boolean hitPaddle(){  

     boolean didHit = false;  

     //this just checks if the ball is lined up between the top and   

     //bottom right-hand corners of the human paddle  

     if((pLeft.getPos() - 10) <= ball.getY() && (pLeft.getPos() + 70) > ball.getY()){  

         //sets didHit to true  

         didHit = true;  

     }  

     return didHit;  

 }
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help sorry to ask a dumb question but where will this if statment go and for when i create the score method should it be anything special?

Comment: The if statement says that if the ball goes out of those locations then it will do whats inside, the printing score line should go inside your paintComponent method (as g2d not g, my bad). The if statement would best go into another method then that method called inside your actionPerformed methods

Comment: hi i added the if statement in a new method in the ball class then i called it in the action performed methods and nothing happens. the bats still go off the screen.

public void batBoundary()
 {
  if(x < 10 | x > 140 | y < 10 | y > 140) {
         xa = xa * -1; //switch direction of ball(bounce)
         ya = ya * -1;
  }
 }

Comment: I feel like something is overriding your xa and ya variable but I don't know what, why I think this  is because those control the movements of the ball and when it hits the boundary the ball should bounce the opposite way

Comment: ok i could leave out the bounadary thing but how will i get the ball to collide with the bats?